# Why JMeter varibles aren't set from JSR223 Groovy Assertion?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I'm trying to set Jmeter variables extracted from Jmeter properties inside JSR223 Groovy Assertion.

Jmeter properties in which I'm interested looks like:

> ```
> ...
> created_blob_A_6= fde65de0-3e32-11e8-a5b4-3906549016d8
> created_blob_A_8= fef92d70-3e32-11e8-a5b4-3906549016d8
> created_blob_A_9= ff775e20-3e32-11e8-bac3-e51250ffea15
> created_blob_B_1= fd7302a0-3e32-11e8-a5b4-3906549016d8
> created_blob_B_10= 00141350-3e33-11e8-bac3-e51250ffea15
> ...
> ```

In order to extract values from Jmeter properties, I've created JSR223 Groovy the following Assertion script:

```
def readParamPrefix = 'created_blob'
def writeParamPrefix = 'blob_to_delete'
def chucnkTypes = 'A'..'E'
def newBlobCounter = 1

chucnkTypes.each{ chunkLetter ->
    (1..10).each{ streamNumber ->
        String readParamName = readParamPrefix + '_' + chunkLetter + '_' + streamNumber
        log.info('Read param name: ' + readParamName)
        String writeParamName = writeParamPrefix + '_' + newBlobCounter
        log.info('Write param name: ' + writeParamName)
        String blob_id_to_delete = props.get(readParamName).toString().trim()
        log.info('' + readParamName + ' => ' + writeParamName + ' (' + blob_id_to_delete + ')')
        vars.put(writeParamName.toString(), blob_id_to_delete.toString())
        newBlobCounter++
    }
}
```

The script doesn't work for JMeter variables, but works fine for JMeter properties. Here is how JMeter properies look like:

> ```
> JMeterProperties:
> ...
> blob_to_delete_1=9b1c4f40-3e36-11e8-a5b4-3906549016d8
> blob_to_delete_10=9da5e050-3e36-11e8-bac3-e51250ffea15
> blob_to_delete_11=9b235420-3e36-11e8-bac3-e51250ffea15
> blob_to_delete_50=9b656630-3e36-11e8-bac3-e51250ffea15
> ```

Could you tell me, how I can fix my code for setting up JMeter variables correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your code:

[image: JMeter Groovy Variables]

So I would recommend:

- Checking *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries
- Checking what variables are defined using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information on getting to the bottom of JMeter script failure or unexpected behavior.

[image: JMeter Debug Variables]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ${varName} in scripts, Notice [JSR223 Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223):

> ensure the script does not use any variable using ${varName} as caching would take only first value of ${varName}. Instead use :
>   vars.get("varName")
>   You can also pass them as Parameters to the script and use them this way.

After you change it, look for errors in logs if it still doesn't works

Comment: I removed all dollar signs ($) before variable names, it didn't help.
Also, there are no errors in JMeter logs

Comment: @Eugene you should not remove $ sign, it should be converted to `vars.get("varName")`